# Referencing a range of columns in dplyr

Tags: r, filter, sum, dplyr

let say I have a data frame `df` like that

```
    txt    A1    A2    B1    B2
1   ala    6      9    12    23
2   ata    1      3    3     11
....
```

I would like to use `dplyr` for filtering the rows based on a sum of a range of variables. 
I tried:

```
filter(df, sum(A2:B1)>10)
```

.... but it does not work.

Could anyone suggest a solution in `dplyr`? And yes I know it can be done differently by simple subsetting.

Comment: `filter(df, A2+B1>10)`?

Comment: I know in this particular case you can simply add the two but imagine I have tens of columns in the range

Comment: yeah, that's what I thought...

Comment: the function you are looking for is `rowSums` in this case, `rowSums(df[,3:4])` would do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most `dplyr`-esque way would be:

```
df %>%
  filter(rowSums(select_(., 'A2:B1')) > 10)
```

Which gives:

```
#  txt A1 A2 B1 B2
#1 ala  6  9 12 23
```

Comment: One more question. Is it possible without pipping?

Comment: @kwicher Try `filter(df, rowSums(select_(df, 'A2:B1')) > 10)`

Comment: @kwicher glad it helped

Comment: `select_()` is deprecated. Use `filter(rowSums(select(., A2:B1)) > 10)` note no underscore and no quotes around the columns.

Answer (score 4):

We can get the indexes first and then use `rowSums`,

```
v1 <- which(names(df) == 'A2') #find first column
#[1] 3
v2 <- which(names(df) == 'B1') #find last column
#[1] 4
df[rowSums(df[v1:v2])>10,]
#  txt A1 A2 B1 B2
#1 ala  6  9 12 23
```